# Switch on post - electrical?

Tags: electrical

Anyone know what this switch does/did?  I haven't tried to locate where it goes yet but haven't seen anything like it before.

[image: switch on post]

Comment: Seems to be lockable on/off.  A bit more industrial than normal household type.

Comment: It switches something on and off.

Comment: I had something outside just like this for my outdoor basketball court flood lights.

Comment: Start by determining if it's active using a non-contact voltage detector. - it may be part of a disconnected circuit.

Answer (score 14):

That is just a regular outdoor weatherproof cover for a single gang toggle switch. It could control lights, a pump, anything that's switched. It has a tab with a hole in it for a pad lock  to secure the switch in the "on" or "off" position but it's not very strong.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to find out what it was or is connected to is to trace the wiring, or to flip the switch and try to figure out what changed.

I'd start by trying to determine what breaker it's on; the previous owner's notes may then tell you what it was for.

If that didn't help, only thought I've got short of digging it up is a proper wire tracer; isolate it, put a signal onto it, and use a receiver to try to follow that signal.

UNLESS this powers something away from the house. In that case, you may be able to convince the buried-utilities-safety people to come and try to scan for buried conduit that might interfere with excavation on your property. Be prepared for them to leave spray paint marks on your sidewalk and lawn to mark what they've found. Ask locally how to contact them, since the number to reach your local folks varies.

Comment: Correction accepted, tnx.